# Ubuntu 12.10 will not shutdown/reboot. How could I solve this?

Tags: shutdown, reboot

Ubuntu 12.10 will not shutdown or restart, even by using terminal commands such as:

`sudo shutdown -r now`, `init 0`, `halt`, etc.

I have noticed one thing, that whenever I reinstall NVIDIA drivers, the system can shutdown/reboot temporarily, but after one or two shutdowns/reboots, the problem happens again.

I'm not sure exactly when this problem started, but it was sometime after Tuesday or Wednesday April 10, when I installed automatic updates.

System:

> Memory 3.9 GiB
>   Processor Intel Core 2 Duo CPU T7700 @ 2.40GHz x 2
>   Graphics GeForce 8600M GT/PCIe/SSE2
>   OS type 64-bit
>   Disk 113.9 GB

Comment: What error is displayed when shutting down? What happens?

Comment: Should I post my /var/log/messages file here? No messages show up once I try to reboot or shutdown. The screen just goes black. Something I noticed today is that if I reboot right after the desktop screen loads, the reboot goes through. If I wait too long, then it will hang and not reboot or shutdown until I hard shutdown. Rebooting/shutting down also works after I log off.

Comment: There's really no consistent behavior. It seems that the more I try to shutdown or reboot, the less likely it is that any of those processes will work. Reboot and shutdown -h now were working during the first few tries today, but then neither of them worked. I guess it's just some sort of system instability.

Answer (score 0):

you can force a reboot by entering the following

`echo 1 > /proc/sys/kernel/sysrq`

`echo b > /proc/sysrq-trigger`

have you tried physically restarting the computer?
if you don't have physical access be warned that if you force a reboot the computer might not come back online. force reboots are normally only needed if hardware has failed

Comment: Something I noticed today is that if I reboot right after the desktop screen loads, the reboot goes through. If I wait too long, then it will hang and not reboot or shutdown until I hard shutdown.

Comment: There's really no consistent behavior. It seems that the more I try to shutdown or reboot, the less likely it is that any of those processes will work. Reboot and shutdown -h now were working during the first few tries today, but then neither of them worked. I guess it's just some sort of system instability.